# Markdown not visible in JupyterLab 1.1.4

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

After trying to enable some JupyterLab extensions, I've been running into a problem. Markdown text is not visible after executing it (JupyterLab = 1.1.4/1.1.3).

Here's the Markdown text before execution:
[image]

And here's what I see after executing the above cells

[image]

Any idea what's causing this?

Comment: You will need to elaborate a bit more on your question. How did you install, how did you enable the extension, environment, etc. Check out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: On JupyterLab (v1.0.2) you have to select a cell but not be editing it, and press a lowercase `m` to convert from code-cell to markdown-cell. Then if you run that cell, it will render. (I couldn't find convert to markdown on the top-nav menu options)